# Is storing a reference to a (possibly) temporary object legal as long as the reference doesn't outlive the object?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

After reading about [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and the handy [`overloaded`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) trick I set myself a challenge (an exercise) to write a helper that would allow me to write

```
visit(variant).with([](int){}, [](char){});
```

instead of

```
std::visit(overloaded{[](int){}, [](char){}}, variant);
```

I'd also like it to work in other cases, like

```
VariantT variant;
VisitorT visitor;

visit(variant).with(visitor);
visit(VariantT{std::in_place_type<int>, 1}).with(visitor);

const VariantT constVariant;
visit(constVariant).with([](auto&&){});
```

You get the idea.

Here's what I came up with (note that I've changed the name from `overloaded` to `Visitor`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

template <typename... T>
struct Visitor : public T...
{
    using T::operator()...;
};

template <typename... T>
Visitor(T...)->Visitor<T...>;

template <typename VariantT>
struct Helper
{
    Helper(VariantT& variant)
    : m_variant{variant}
    {}
    Helper(const Helper&) = delete;
    Helper(Helper&&) = delete;
    Helper& operator=(const Helper&) = delete;
    Helper& operator=(Helper&&) = delete;
    ~Helper() = default;

    template <typename VisitorT, typename... VisitorsT>
    decltype(auto) with(VisitorT&& visitor,
                        VisitorsT&&... visitors) && // this function is ref-qualified so we can only call this on a temp object and we can
                                                    // be sure that the variant lives at least as long as us
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(visitors) == 0)
        {
            return std::visit(std::forward<VisitorT>(visitor), m_variant);
        }
        else
        {
            return std::visit(Visitor{visitor, visitors...}, m_variant);
        }
    }

private:
    VariantT& m_variant;
};

template <typename VariantT>
decltype(auto) visit(VariantT&& variant)
{
    // no forwarding here, even if an rvalue was passed, pass an lvalue ref
    return Helper{variant};
}

int main()
{
    visit(std::variant<int>{std::in_place_type<int>, -7})
        .with([](int i) { std::cout << "got an int: " << i << std::endl; },
              [](std::string str) { std::cout << "got a string: " << str << std::endl; });

    std::variant<int, std::string> v = "String";

    visit(v).with([](int i) { std::cout << "got an int: " << i << std::endl; },
                  [](std::string str) { std::cout << "got a string: " << str << std::endl; });

    visit(v).with([](int& i) { i += 7; },
                  [](std::string& str) { str += "modified"; });

    std::cout << visit(v).with([](int i) { return std::to_string(i); },
                               [](std::string str) { return str; }) << std::endl;
}
```

The question is: is storing references in the `Helper` like that perfectly legal?
My understanding is that temporary objects live until the end of the expression, so I guess this is ok?
Will it do The Right Thing? Are there any pitfalls in that code?

I've tested this code on both msvc and gcc and I'm not seeing anything wrong, but it doesn't mean this works fine in all cases.

Comment: Yes, this is safe. When you pass in a temporary visitor it lives until the end of the full expression. `with(...)` is a part of the expression so it will outlive the call.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you special case a single argument?

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking maybe it can be used with a stateful visitor or something. The second case is only used with lambdas.

Comment: Even more, there's absolutely nothing wrong with keeping a reference to a destroyed object. But only as long as it's not used.

Comment: Since you don't intend on storing instances of `Helper`, you could probably keep the "value-specification" `VariantT` in `Helper`. This way, you could call even visit with consuming operations, which is not possible with your version. See https://godbolt.org/z/-6X3ci

Comment: FYI: in C++20, you can omit the `Visitor` deduction guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obvious problem is that you can have things like

```
decltype(auto) silly() {
    std::variant<int, std::string> v = "String";
    return visit(v);
}

int main()
{
    silly().with([](auto){ std::cout << "dangling" << std::endl; };
}
```

But such things are relatively easy to spot in review.